# Getting Rid of Number Stored as Text with SSIS Script Task

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

I have two script tasks in my SSIS package. One uses OLEDB to build an Excel file from a view, the other is "attempting" to format some columns and their current values to Numeric. I have tried different iterations of the code below and other things I have found online but nothing seems to work. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApplicaiton = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            excelApplicaiton.Visible = false;
            excelApplicaiton.DisplayAlerts = false;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApplicaiton.Workbooks.Open(Filename: EnrollmentExcelFolderPath + "\\" + EnrollmentExcelName + ".xlsx");

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

            // Format columns to numeric B,L,M,S,T,AA,AB,AH,AJ,AK and AM
            Range cells = excelWorkbook.Worksheets["Data"].Cells;
            cells[1, 2].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0";
            cells[1, 12].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0";
            cells[1, 13].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0";
            cells[1, 19].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0";
            cells[1, 20].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0";
            cells[1, 27].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0";
            cells[1, 28].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0";
            cells[1, 34].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0";
            cells[1, 36].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0";
            cells[1, 37].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0";
            cells[1, 39].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0";

            // convert values in cells
            cells[1, 2].Value = cells[1, 2].Value;
            cells[1, 12].Value = cells[1, 12].Value;
            cells[1, 13].Value = cells[1, 13].Value;
            cells[1, 19].Value = cells[1, 19].Value;
            cells[1, 20].Value = cells[1, 20].Value;
            cells[1, 27].Value = cells[1, 27].Value;
            cells[1, 28].Value = cells[1, 28].Value;
            cells[1, 34].Value = cells[1, 34].Value;
            cells[1, 36].Value = cells[1, 36].Value;
            cells[1, 37].Value = cells[1, 37].Value;
            cells[1, 39].Value = cells[1, 39].Value;

            excelWorkbook.SaveAs(EnrollmentExcelFolderPath + "\\" + EnrollmentExcelName + "_Formatted.xlsx", 
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                true, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, 
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            excelWorkbook.Close();
            excelApplicaiton.Quit();
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApplicaiton);
```

Comment: My guess is that the value that is being copied back to the cell is not the value you intend. If you apply an explicit type cast before assigning, does that make it any better?

Comment: If you're converting a whole column from text to a number, you should consider using `.TextToColumns` it's pretty quick and efficient and you can use a variable instead of explicitly referencing all those cells, which seems prone to error.

Comment: billinkc, I have tried both a cast and convert in the SQL that builds the file, and the columns post formatting come out as "Custom" and still Number Stored as Text. I am not sure what I have to do to resolve this and I don't want to rebuild it from scratch.